# Android splash screen delay

Tags: java, android, delay, splash-screen

I have an animation for my splash screen and on some phones which take longer to load things, it starts mid animation.

The splash screen is really an activity that has a View, in which the animation is drawn. Is it possible to wait for the screen to load and then start the thread in the View? I mean can I somehow check if I can begin the animation and it will be shown, the whole thing

Comment: How are you currently attaching the animation to your view? Is it a part of the layout? If so, it might help to load and run the animation in your activity's onResume instead.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't call it an animation. In my SplashActivity which is the first activity to open in onCreate method I create a SurfaceView that has its own thread and it draws the animation.

Comment: So can you wait for onResume to start it?

Comment: To start what exactly? The Surface View? I create it in OnCreate and setContentView(view) there also

Comment: You said that your SurfaceView has a thread that runs the animation. I'm suggesting that you don't start the thread, or at least don't run the animation, until the activity that owns the view has its onResume called. At that point your activity can call a method on your surface view, which can start the animation going.

Comment: It's God's way of saying don't do it.  http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and DON'T use a splash screen. On Android guidelines Google is extremely against splash screens because they give some sort of slowish UI perception to the user, and it's not a good thing at all.

If you absolutely need to wait for some sort of data to finish loading/network query you can do it much more elegantly by letting the app load normally and give the user a loading indicator (e.g. SwipeToRefreshLayout from the v7 support lib).

Not actually answering your question but this is a much more elegant solution for a completely wrong approach for a good UX. The Animation.AnimationListener has a callback called onAnimationEnd where you can do whatever after the animation has finished.